# Entity with 2 one-to-one properties to a common entity type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a couple of entity classes.

Parent:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
    }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Child Boy { get; set; }

    public virtual Child Girl { get; set; }
}
```

and Child:

```
public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

So, Parent has 2 one-to-one relationships with Child.

In OnModelCreating, I added the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasKey<int>(e => e.ParentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .HasKey<int>(e => e.ChildId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasOptional<Child>(p => p.Boy)
    .WithRequired(c => c.Parent)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasOptional<Child>(p => p.Girl)
    .WithRequired(c => c.Parent)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But I get an error when creating the database:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'Example.Parent_Boy' >was not loaded because the type 'Example.Child' is not available.

How can I configure the model so that my entity can have 2 nullable, one-to-one relationships to the same entity type?

Comment: whats the criteria for boy and girl? is there any flag or somthing?

Comment: No, nor does my real life problem. I'm guessing I can't use the Parent property twice for 2 different things. Which is fine, I can rethink.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
public Parent()
{
}

public int ParentId { get; set; }

public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }

public Child Boy{ get{ return Children.First(<BoyCondition>); } }
public Child Girl{ get{ return Children.First(<GirlCondition>); } }
```

Dont forget to ignore boy and girl propertys

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Ignore(m => m.Boy);
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Ignore(m => m.Girl);
```

Comment: It would work, yes. But there's no enforcement in the database. What I want is are tables structured like:

**Child**

ChildID  (PK, int, not null)

**Parent**

ParentID (PK, int, not null)
Boy_ChildID (FK, int, null)
Girl_ChildID (FK, int, null)

Which is exactly what EF creates for me if I don't have the navigational properties back to the parent. That's what confuses it.